# System Setting is not working and it doesn't show anything

Tags: 14.04, system-settings

This is what I get when I go to the System Settings (Ubuntu 14.04):

[image]

I tried to reinstall ubuntu-desktop et similia but anything changed

But if I uninstall ubuntu-desktop, System Settings shows me a few options like this:

[image]

What should I do?

**EDIT:**

I have already tried

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @Tim is not a duplicate. Read both the questions entirely. That solution doesn't work for me, as I said.

Comment: It is a duplicate, it just didn't work. I have read both - I answered the dupe.

Comment: did you try the second answer?

Comment: @Tim yes it's about 2 weeks I'm looking for a solution and I know all these posts is askubuntu. My problem is a little different because my System Settings doesn't show anything.

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center`

Comment: @Tim yes. I'll edit the question in order to show what commands I've tried

Comment: I may have found a solution to your issue http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183338 about half way down the second page this guy fixes the issue, I could not understand what they actually did maby someone can take a look and see what they think

Comment: Also try sudo apt-get install --reinstall Unity-Control-Center my source for this is here https://launchpad.net/unity-control-center, says it has replaced gnome-control-centre in 14.04